# Group, concatenate and return 3 columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Here are some data:

```
data = data.frame(
    name=c("bob", "bob", "mary", "ann", "ann", "ann"),
    colour=c("blue", "blue", "yellow", "green", "green", "blue"),
    number=c(2,2,3,4,4,4))

data

data %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(colours = paste(unique(colour), collapse = ' '))
```

How can I group these data as described above but keep the column `number`? Within `data`, all Bob's will = 2, all Mary's = 3 and all Ann's = 4. Thus, I need to return just the first instance of each number for each unique `name` value.

Expected output:

```
 name     colours number
1  ann green blue      4
2  bob       blue      2
3 mary     yellow      3
```

Comment: Add `number` to the columns in `group_by` if you expect it to stay the same for each name

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Add number to the `group_by`, `group_by(name, number)`. This is generally good because if your assumption that each name corresponds to exactly one number is incorrect, you will see the odd combinations.
2. Aggregate number in your `summarise`, picking the value that you want, e.g., `number = first(number)` as an additional statement inside `summarise`. This is more computationally efficient, but if your assumption that each name corresponds to exactly one number is incorrect, you will either get an unexpected result or you may never notice.

Comment: Great, thank you. I will accept this answer soon (you responded so quickly that SO won't let me accept the answer for another 8 minutes!).